# Matrix input based on random value output (Matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I am looking to use the output of a random value to choose the column which will be input into a new matrix, called Matrix1.

I have something like the following:

```
a = [1 2 3 4; 5 3 6 2; 9 8 1 4];
n = length(a(1,:))-1;
RandomValue = round(rand()*n+1);
Matrix1 = [];
L=3;
for i=n:-1:1
    RandomValue
    if RandomValue < L
        Matrix1 = [a(:,i) Matrix1];
        a(:, i) = [];
        Matrix1
    end
end
```

E.g. If the random value is 2, I would like to place [2;3;8] into the Matrix1 (based on the value of the first row). How could I modify the code, so instead of i it is that Randomvalue number?

Comment: Fix your formatting. I'd do it myself but I can't really see how it's supposed to be.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do here? What is the outcome of this procedure? do you simply want to permute the columns of your `a` matrix?

Comment: What I am looking to do is take the input values in a and outputting to Matrix1 based on the RandomValue of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow you exactly, but I can't see why some variant of

```
Matrix1 = [a(:,round(rand()*n+1)) Matrix1]
```

isn't appropriate.  Better than rounding a `rand` would be to use the `randi` function which returns a pseudo-random integer, maybe

```
Matrix1 = [a(:,randi(n)) Matrix1]
```

But if, as @angainor has suggested, you are trying to permute the columns of your input matrix, then look to the `permute` function.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work but I am getting some duplicate columns in the output. I will look into it some more ...